# What's a good, if any, .NET Windows automation library?

Tags: c#, .net, ui-automation

I'm looking for a library that can be used in native .NET code, just like any .NET assembly. The purpose of the library must be to automate Windows (push a button, select a window, send keys, record & playback, that sort of thing).

So: the library is supposed to be used natively in .NET, but the automation itself must be able to target any native or .NET Windows application that can receive user input.

---

Suggestions so far:

- [benPearce suggested AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library/2052978#2052978). It has a DLL, which is native Win32 but not native .NET and cannot be used without use of .NET Interop.
- [Chris Dunaway suggested Global Mouse Keyboard Lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library/2053153#2053153). This came closest, but is not an automation lib. It just helps setting up keyboard and mouse hooks.
- [pm100 suggested Microsoft's WPF UI Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library/2052959#2052959). This one is pretty good, albeit that it's not available if you develop in .NET 2.0 and it requires the WPF to be installed on the system. It can, however, automate everything from Win32 apps to HTML in a browser.
- [JasonTrue suggested WebAI from ArtOfTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library/2053015#2053015). This is a testing framework mainly geared towards browsers and web applications. It is unfortunately not well suitable for use for Windows automation.

If nothing else appears available, I'll probably choose Microsoft's UI Automation and upgrade any projects that require it that are still in .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5, if possible. But I hope for a more widely applicable automation framework (.NET prior to 2.0 does not need to be supported).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you looked at [the White framework](http://www.codeplex.com/white)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks good and it takes the pain away of using the UI Framework of WPF. However, it has the same drawbacks as WPF (when called from WinForms for instance), but it is possibly the best solution so far.

Comment: If you also have external Controls, you may want to verify that they can be automated with White: In this case you might want to use this http://www.codeplex.com/UIAutomationVerify .

Comment: After some thought I decided to accept your answer. It is not exactly what I wanted (it limits me to use WPF when I want to include White or MS UI Automation), but it's arguably the best offer so far. Thanks!

Comment: Actually White is just a wrapper over MS UI Automation.

Answer (score 8):

microsoft's own built in one is fine

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx

not restricted to wpf as some seem to think.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this new development. Surely interesting, but it locks me down to WPF. Considering I nearly only do .NET 3.5+ development (when I do .NET projects, that is) that shouldn't be a real problem though.

Comment: I don't think this locks you into WPF; it's the Windows standard UI automation library, and just happens to work with WPF now. MS Active Accessibility is your best option if you need to work downlevel.

Comment: I don't seem to make myself very clear, sorry about that. I want to use the libs from programming code. Which requires WPF (which isn't a problem). Yes, of course it can automate anything in Windows, I totally understand, but that wasn't the point... ;-)

Comment: +1. As recommended in MSDN magazine http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163465.aspx

Comment: It was a tough decision between your answer and White. But White is so much easier to use, it really takes away the complexity of Microsoft UI Automation, while still being able to falling back to the core if I want or need to. It is still in development, but it has potential. Both are WPF, no basic .NET application can use the lib, you need to include WPF. But that's just something I have to accept (or use hardcode AutoIt or CSharpScript).

Answer (score 8):

I have used [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) in the past with success.

Comment: Looks quite like something I need (and it rings a bell, too). Tx

Comment: Beat me to it! :) Yes, I would say check out AutoItX, which is a way to use AutoIt functionality from a DLL.

Comment: Since I actually asked for a .NET lib: I don't imm. see how it can be used from within .NET. Can you either show an example or point to one how it can be called from .NET?

Comment: Some ruby test automation libraries do it by essentially creating a pipe to the I/O of the AutoIt executable. Ugly but it works.

Comment: I think the bit of info missing is that AutoIt automates at the Windows level not .Net level, so pressing buttons on a form or setting contents of a textbox, could be any form.

Comment: that's not really what I mean, I fully understand that it's possible to use AutoIt to automate an existing .NET program. But how can you create a .NET program that uses AutoIt (like a lib or a .NET assembly) to automate Windows.

Comment: If you include either the executable or the DLL version (AutoItX), you can either use the hacky method (System.Process.Start, for example) and call the AutoIt command-line app, or you can use normal DLL Interop mechanisms if you're using the DLL.

Comment: Jason, thanks for the explanation, I totally agree and understand. But I was looking for .NET library. Calling into native code using interop is not what I call calling a .NET library...

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't seen it yet, and a commercial library is acceptable, you might check out Ranorex:

http://www.ranorex.com/

I used Ranorex 1.5 quite a bit to write small C# UI automation utilities.  It was pretty effective!  Development seemed faster compared to using the MS UI Automation API directly, since Ranorex has a lot of useful convenience methods already available.

I haven't used Ranorex 2 very much yet, though.

In Ranorex 1.5, there was also support for traditional Win32 development in C++, but I didn't use it.  As far as I know, that's still available in Ranorex 2.

I can't speak to the quality of the record/playback support in Ranorex since I never used that feature.

One final plus: Their support team was really responsive and helpful anytime I emailed them.

Comment: I just have one question. Does it support testing of DevExpress controls like the Grid?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Tools for automated GUI testing on windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20101220094104/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120359/tools-for-automated-gui-testing-on-windows)

Comment: Good list, comes down to AutoIt of BenPearce, effectively ;-)

Answer (score 2):

[This library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalmousekeyboardlib.aspx) is pretty interesting and is fairly simple.  Perhaps it will help you.

Comment: That's definitely interesting! Not actually an automation lib per se, but it's surely usable and up to that task it seems. I'll have a deeper look at it.

Answer (score 2):

I would still suggest `FlaUI` for autoamating .Net Desktop,Mobile apps. Its based on Microsoft `UIA` libraries and have support for external controls like the `DevExpress` Grid too
Moreover, it is built on top of `TestStack.White` so indeed a very good library and has a `github` page also

Answer (score 1):

I have used [WebAii from ArtOfTest](http://www.artoftest.com/products/webaii.aspx) with a fair degree of success in automating integration testing for a Silverlight app. It also supports WinForms and Web applications.

Microsoft UI Automation, the successor to Active Accessibility, can do almost all of the Windows UI automation you would need.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that browser-automation? I'm really looking for Windows automation. Interesting to keep, though for other types of projects :)

Comment: You're right, it's certainly more focused on that domain, but it exposes Win32 controls as well. Microsoft UI Automation works for most automation that doesn't have to interact with browsers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_UI_Automation

Answer (score 1):

How about CSharpScript, here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs-script_for_cp.aspx) about it on Codeproject, and here's the [link](http://www.csscript.net/) to the main website. Furthermore, it is familiar C#, scripted which can be used to automate anything.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: That looks like a promising project that has its merits, but being a scripting language, how can it be applied for automation of "any" Windows application?

Comment: I wouldn't define it as a scripting language per se, the C# code can be used as a program in its own right, if you think of the Windows Scripting Host, or even AutoIt, even use p/invoke in the code, that's the flexibility of it.