# Internet Explorer settings in Selenium webdriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to untick 'check for server certificate ' checkbox in internet explorer settings tab before the selenium execution code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in options for the [InternetExplorerDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) to enable this, but here are two solutions that might help:

1. [Custom registry entries](http://automationoverflow.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/registry-entries-for-internet-explorer.html)
2. ["Just click the override link"](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6343/11509)

See also: [How can we get Watir-Webdriver to work with the IE invalid cert screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101700/how-can-we-get-watir-webdriver-to-work-with-the-ie-invalid-cert-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Use UIAutomation instead. Selenium is only limited to the Web Automation.

[c# ui automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100978/c-sharp-ui-automation)