# How to make a program that checks if a different window is open, then fills in forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make a program that checks if a specific window (from a separate program) is open, then if it's open, it will fill in forms automatically in that window. I have no idea where to start, I looked it up online and couldn't find anything on the topic.

An example of this is trying to fill in login information in a separate windows form automatically.

How would this be made? Is it even possible? If possible, I would like any answers in C#.

Comment: Is there a reason this has to be done in C#?  AutoHotkey sounds like the perfect match for this.  http://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 3):

I would look at the the [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294%28VS.85%29.aspx) and in the [System.Windows.Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.aspx) namespace.

Answer (score 0):

AutoIt is a scripting language especially designed for this purpose

http://www.autoitscript.com/

If you really need this inside a C# program, you can use the COM interface of AutoIt.

EDIT: here is a very similar question:

[What's a good, if any, .NET Windows automation library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library)

The answers given there should help you.

Answer (score 0):

To find a window with a specific title, use interop from C# to call the Win32 function [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which will give you the windows' characteristics and titles.  You can then activate the window and call [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) to send keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible.

You'll need win32 APIs for interop (getting handles to other applications' controls and sending windows messages to them); this site is invaluable: http://pinvoke.net/

You'll need to understand controls and how to target them. Invaluable to this is Winspector Spy, but I think this product may no longer be around. Look for Winspector alternatives. I know that one comes with AutoHotkey (free), but I don't think it is as full-featured as was Winspector.

Although you can probably write some nice C# wrappers around this stuff, most of the work has to be done in the win32 APIs, not .NET framework classes/methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you can introduce a dependency on WPF, look into using WPF's [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) framework. It's meant to be used for both automated UI testing and assistive technology like screen readers, so it would definitely work for filling out a form in another application.

Answer (score 0):

Is this for a web app or a desktop app? The answer will vary greatly depending on which one it is.

Web sites are much easier IMO todo this with - a quick perl script using curl is probably the easiest way, and a great learning experience too. You could also use C# and use the curl API, or just make C# Run() calls to execute command line calls to curl (console app) itself. **The bottom line: you need to make POST/GET HTTP calls with the given info.** Fiddler is your friend here - use it to find out how the website is expecting the calls and then mimic it using curl.

A windows application would require some PInvoke calls to windows message pump on the given app; e.g. C++ would be easier here depending on your experience/requirements, or you can easily wrap C++ API calls in C# using PInvoke. Either way, AFAIK there is no way to do this for a windows app in 100% managed code - I could certainly be wrong, but I've never seen it and am interested myself to find it's possible. **Bottom line: you need to make calls to the win32 API to find which window it is - and then send keystrokes to that window in the appropriate places.**

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Spy++ or some other tool to get the class name and windows name.  They should probably be configurable, don't recommmend hard codeing the values.   Here we do a loop and look for the window and then close it.  I've included the appropriate imports, windows API signatures and sample code.

```
//DLL Imports

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

//For Sending Keys

using System.Windows.Forms;



        // Get a handle to an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName,
            string lpWindowName);

        // Activate an application window.
        [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

Sample Code:

```
    IntPtr handle= IntPtr.Zero;
    int retryCount = 0;

    //Try until max is reached
    while (retryCount < 30)
    {
        //Get a handle to the window  
        handle= FindWindow(WindowClassName, WindowName);

        //We found the window
        if (handle!= IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            retryCount = 30;
            //Send Close Command 
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
            SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}");
        }

        retryCount++;
        //Wait 2 seconds before trying again
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }
```