# Copy Selected Area's text to clipboard

Tags: c#, text, copy, clipboard, selected

I am pretty new to C# and programming in general.
I am wondering if there is a way to implement the following feature:

1. in my C# program have a `textbox` (named `tb1`) and `button` (named `bt1`).
2. When I click `bt1`, my cursor will change to "selector"
3. I switch to program where I need the value to be taken from
4. I select text that I need to be copied to my C# program
5. Selected text will appear in `bt1`

WindowsXP/Windows Vista/7

PS - I know how to get text from the clipboard and how to set text to the clipboard, what I need is the way to capture ANY text AFTER I press the button. 
For example- I have 10 textboxes; each textbox has a button.

The process would be:

1. button1 click -> select text in another application -> which is auto-pasted to textbox1
2. button2 click -> select text in another application -> which is auto-pasted to textbox2
3. button3 click -> select text in another application -> which is auto-pasted to textbox3

etc.

Comment: Just guessing, but is this homework or your own exercise? It's ok to ask homework questions, as long as you specify so.

Comment: You could do it with something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wfspy.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify whether the user can click Ctrl-C in step (4) when inside that other application. If so, the selected text can indeed appear in your application: all you need to do is reading the Clipboard object, as in `Clipboard.GetText()`.

A good introduction with some [how-to's can be found here at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/clipboard01.aspx).

---

In the case where step (4) in your question should auto-copy the selected text to the clipboard from a foreign application, consider using an automation-tool like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [the White Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/white) instead (more options in this question on automation: [What's a good, if any, .NET Windows automation library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library)).