# Is there any way to run windows form function from command line (cmd file)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I need to be able to run a Windows Forms function or event (for example a button click) from a command line.  How could I do this?

I can't use a console or windows service due to certain constraints.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *windows form function*?

Comment: Guess he means manual raising certain events of UI controls on his WinForms app from cmd?

Comment: I guess you could create a new program with the code you want to execute in the `Main` function. Would that work?

Comment: I have window form, I need to run the form using command file. Is there any way. That is my question...?

Comment: well, a form is part of the *program*. You can start the program from a command file. A program always starts executing in the `Main` function. There's no way to start execution in another part of the code. Not to my knowledge anyway.

Comment: I can keep wahtever I need to do in one fy

Answer (score 0):

If you mean re-use a method in your Windows Forms application in a command line (Console) application, then simply reference the assembly containing the class and call that method, a bit like this

```
static void Main()
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.SomeButton_Click();
}
```

Note that for this to work the `SomeButton_Click` method **and** the `Form1` class must be public.  If this is what you want to do then this is a good indication that the logic contained in `SomeButton_Click` should be refactored to some common utility class.

If alternatively you want to simulate a button click in a running Windows Forms application then you have a couple of options

- [Windows Automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052915/whats-a-good-if-any-net-windows-automation-library) (simulating mouse & keyboard events from code)
- [Inter process communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices) (sending a message from your command line program to your Windows Forms program to ask it to run that method)

There are many different ways to achieve either of these however both are more complex than just calling a method - it would help if you provided more detail on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this with a Powershell script: [UI Automation with Windows PowerShell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx)